# Shipping surcharge on cartthrob orders

Tags: cartthrob

I need to add a flat-rate summer shipping surcharge on all orders. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is duplicating my shipping plugin, so that I have a summer shipping plugin as well as the regular one.